# How to display superscript in Sharepoint List value?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list, superscript

How do I format a Sharepoint list value to display superscript such as cubic feet, square feet, etc?

Comment: What is your SharePoint version?

Comment: Sharepiont 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint should do not provide a function to display superscript.

You could try some input method software that contains superscript and subscript symbol libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I am not actually sure if this will solve your problem. What if you use multiline field in list with full Html option (rich text or something similar). I think it should somehow support what you are looking for. I made a quick test and here is the result
[image]

Comment: This is helpful, but I am unable to write/read HTML to/from the Sharepoint list. I need to use plain text if possible.

Comment: then I am not sure. why html is out of the option? maybe we could work on this part?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this using PowerApps as the data input method. The ASCII code for cubic superscript is `Char(0179)`. Writing to the Sharepoint data source, plain text column type, using `"ft." & Char(0179)` did the trick.

As you both point out, it can likely be accomplished using a software library or plain html as well (though with the html method, you'd likely need to use RichText type column).